# How do I add category names to my seaborn boxplot when my data is from a python dictionary?

Tags: boxplot, seaborn

I have some data that is sitting in a python dictionary of lists.

How can I use the keys from the dictionary as category labels for this boxplot?
Here is a sample of the dictionary, plot_data:

```
plot_data {
    'Group1': [0.02339976, 0.03235323, 0.12835462, 0.10238375, 0.04223188],
    'Group2': [0.02339976, 0.03235323, 0.12835462, 0.10238375, 0.04223188]
}
```

This code is probably a mess, but here it is:

```
data = plot_data.values()

#Get data in proper format
fixed_data = list(sorted(data))


#Set up the graph parameters
sns.set(context='notebook', style='whitegrid')
sns.axlabel(xlabel="Groups", ylabel="Y-Axis", fontsize=16)


#Plot the graph
sns.boxplot(data=fixed_data, whis=np.inf, width=.18)
sns.swarmplot(data=fixed_data, size=6, edgecolor="black", linewidth=.9)
```

[image: Boxplot with no category labels]

Comment: Any reason not to use a pandas DataFrame?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here how to add category labels "manually":

```py
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, operator as op

plot_data = {
  'Group1': range(10,16),
  'Group2': range(5,15),
  'Group3': range(1,5)
}

# sort keys and values together
sorted_keys, sorted_vals = zip(*sorted(plot_data.items(), key=op.itemgetter(1)))

# almost verbatim from question
sns.set(context='notebook', style='whitegrid')
sns.axlabel(xlabel="Groups", ylabel="Y-Axis", fontsize=16)
sns.boxplot(data=sorted_vals, width=.18)
sns.swarmplot(data=sorted_vals, size=6, edgecolor="black", linewidth=.9)

# category labels
plt.xticks(plt.xticks()[0], sorted_keys)

plt.show()
```

And here the output:
[image: output]